# Display "Chosen" Freeform Composer output in EE Template

Tags: solspace-freeform

I've got everything going smoothly with a single form–the composer, notification and template are all set. Works like a charm. In the template, I called the first form specifically as such:

```
{exp:freeform:composer
  form_name="volunteer_application"
  composer_template_name="some_template"
  return="/"
  }
```

However, I am unsure how to allow the template to grab the form_name chosen in the EE admin–where it gives the user the option to "Choose a Freeform Composer Form to output."

Surely I don't need to create a different template for each form?

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you are using the channel field for Freeform composer? If so, all you need to do is display it like any other field in channel entries output: {my_freeform_field_name}. The Composer template can be set in the upper left hand corner of Composer itself rather than needing it to be a param and your return can be pre-set in the composer template as an override param.

Comment: Yes, we are using the channel field to select from open Composer forms. I have followed your instructions about setting the template in the Composer form itself and everything works great when I am still defining the form_name:

{exp:freeform:composer form_name="volunteer_application" }

However, I still do not comprehend your other instruction to allow the template to grab the chosen form from the channel field...

{exp:freeform:composer form_name=" {my_freeform_field_name}" }

This doesn't work so I am sure I'm not grasping.

Comment: my apologies, i entered very literally "my_freeform_field_name" and only just now realized what buffoonery that was. however, when i enter the actual field name (defined as {frye_form} in the Channel Field settings), it does not work there either: {exp:freeform:composer form_name="{frye_form}"}

Comment: when i enter very simply "{frye_form}" into the template (sans {exp:freeform:composer ... }), i get a PHP error: array_merge(): 
'Argument #2 is not an array
Filename: freeform/ft.freeform.php
Line Number: 238`

Comment: If you use the **Freeform Channel Custom Field**, you do not use {exp:freeform:composer} at all. You simply use the field's name as you would with any simple custom field within {exp:channel:entries}. Here's an example: `{exp:channel:entries /* your other parameters */}{frye_form}{/exp:channel:entries}`. That's all that's needed to display your selected Composer form.